# No module named urls

Tags: python, django, import, admin

After hitting the admin page I am getting an error no named url exceptions?

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named urls
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.5
Python Path:    ['/usr/local/google/Myfiles/cheeserater', '/usr/local/buildtools/current/sitecustomize', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 19 Apr 2011 23:49:27 -0500
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing a `urls.py` file? What is your directory structure look like? Do other pages work? any backgroud you can give?

Answer (score 5):

you need to include admin urls, in your main url file

```
from django.contrib import  admin
admin.autodiscover()

(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)
```